# Cannot show the Toast through the Callback function

Tags: java, android

Here is the httpPost to send the data to server and get the response.

```
public void httpPost(String URL ) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(URL);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.setUseCaches(false);
                        connection.connect();
                        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
    
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                stringBuilder.append(line);
                            }
    
                            callback.success(stringBuilder.toString());
    
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

Here is the Callback function to setup the string from server response.

```
    public interface Callback{
             void success(String string);
        }
```

Click the button and post the data to server. Here can get the response of the string from Callback function but it cannot show the toast.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     server.httpPost("https://google.com/index.php?username=Peter");
                        server.callback =new Server.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(String response) {
                                
                                    Log.d("test",response);
Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                
                            }
                        };
                    
                }
            });
```

[image: Here is the Log.d response]

Comment: Why cant you show the Toast? You did not tell what goes wrong.

Comment: thank you for reply but I have not got the wrong

Answer (score 0):

You must run the Toast on UI thread using the following code:

```
<Activity>.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     (Toast and other UI changes here...)
                }
            });
```